# Error al crear una app en react

Tags: reactjs

tengo un problema, cuando quiero crear una app con npx create-react-app my-app me salen varios errores, el disco de mi pc es nuevo, no tiene nada, supongo que es un error del sistema operativo o que falta algun archivo, detallo errores que me salen aca abajo.

Starting the development server...

> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
> at module.exports (C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
> at handleParseError (C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
> at C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
> at C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
> at C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
>
> ```
> at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
> at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
> ```
>
> C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
> throw err;   ^
>
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
> at module.exports (C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
> at C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
> at C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
> at C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
>
> ```
> at C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
>
> at context.callback (C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
> at C:\proyectos\mern\my-app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103
> ```
>
> {   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope
> routines::initialization error' ],,   library: 'digital envelope
> routines',   reason: 'unsupported',   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
> }

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: hola ezequiel, el problema esta en la version de tu nodejs. Se arregla instalando la version LTS no la ultima. asi que te recomiendo desinstalar la que tienes y te pones la LTS

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo utilizar Vite Js https://vitejs.dev/guide/#trying-vite-online para crear una app de React js.